# XamlParseException on extended ListView in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, listview, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I've been scouring the internet for a week looking for an answer to my question, but nobody else seems to be hitting this issue.

I am migrating an app from Windows Phone 8 Silverlight to Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT, and am having an issue with a custom control I made. In the Silverlight app, I created a custom LongListSelector that I predefined a ItemTemplate for with custom binding and logic. I reuse this LongListSelector in a few different places in the app.

I am trying to do the same thing in my WinRT app, but with ListView. The issue is that when I try to include my custom extended ListView in any XAML page, I get an E_UNKNOWN_ERROR XamlParseException with the Line and Position number set to the end of the opening tag of my ListView.

Here is what my custom ListView's XAML looks like:

```
<ListView
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyAppNamespace"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:sys="using;System;assembly=mscorlib"
    x:Class="MyAppNamespace.CustomListView"
    x:Name="This"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400"
    ItemsSource="{Binding}">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            .... my data template is here ...

        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And my code-behind is this:

```
namespace MyAppNamespace
{
    public partial class CustomListView: ListView
    {
        public CustomListView()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        ... event handlers and custom logic here ...
    }
}
```

And here's how I reference it in another XAML page

```
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyAppNamespace"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Class="MyAppNamespace.SamplePage"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>


        <local:CustomListView DataContext="{Binding Items}"/>
    </Grid>

</Page>
```

The error shows up in Blend and in the design view of the xaml file in Visual Studio. When I run the app and navigate to the page where I am using this control, the error appears on the `LoadComponent` function call within the generated `InitializeComponent`.

The weird thing is that if I switch the root element to `UserControl` and put the `ListView` inside it (and update the base class in the code-behind), then everything works fine, but I'd rather just directly extend the `ListView` then wrap it in a UserControl.

Comment: Is there an InnerException?

Comment: Have you tried isolating the issue? Making it a minimal control with minimal template and then extending property by property, method by method etc.?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it with noting inside my custom ListView, and I still see the same.

There are three levels of exception. The outer-most is `Cannot create an instance of "CustomListView"`. The innerException for that is `TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation`. The inner error for that is `XamlParseException: The text associated with this error code could not be found. E_UNKNOWN_ERROR [Line: 13 Position: 29] `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out!!

I needed to override the `PrepareContainerForItemOverride` and then set the `Loaded` event for the `ListViewItem` passed in as the first parameter. Then, in the event handler, apply the callbacks as needed by traversing the element tree.

`PrepareContainerForItemOverride` will be called every time a row of the `ExtendedListView` is populated with a different element from the `ItemsSource`, but the `Loaded` callback will only be called once per row unless the row is unloaded (you can also add a callback handler for this if needed.

Below is some sample code to help out anyone else who has this issue!!

Here's the relevant contents of ExtendedListView.cs:

```
public sealed class ExtendedListView : ListView
{
    public ExtendedListView()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ExtendedListView);
    }

    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
        ListViewItem lvi = element as ListViewItem;
        lvi.Loaded += lvi_Loaded;
    }

    void lvi_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = sender as ListViewItem;
        ApplyCallbacksToElement(lvi.ContentTemplateRoot);
    }

    private void ApplyCallbacksToElement(DependencyObject element)
    {
        if (null != element)
        {
            int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element);
            for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i);
                // Code for adding element callbacks goes here
                //
                // For example:
                // if (IsButtonAndMatchesCondition(child))
                // {
                //     (child as Button).Click += button_Click;
                // }
                //
                ApplyCallbacksToElement(child);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the relevant content of the Generic.xaml file generated in the Themes folder created after making a new TemplatedControl:

```
<Style TargetType="local:ExtendedListView">
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
            Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="TabNavigation"
            Value="Once" />
    <Setter Property="IsSwipeEnabled"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility"
            Value="Disabled" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility"
            Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode"
            Value="Disabled" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled"
            Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode"
            Value="Enabled" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled"
            Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.ZoomMode"
            Value="Disabled" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled"
            Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerTransitions">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <AddDeleteThemeTransition />
                <ContentThemeTransition />
                <ReorderThemeTransition />
                <EntranceThemeTransition IsStaggeringEnabled="False" />
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!-- Put your custom DataTemplate here -->
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:ExtendedListView">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer"
                                  TabNavigation="{TemplateBinding TabNavigation}"
                                  HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                  IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled}"
                                  VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                  IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled}"
                                  IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}"
                                  IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}"
                                  ZoomMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ZoomMode}"
                                  IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}"
                                  BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}"
                                  AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw">
                        <ItemsPresenter Header="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                        HeaderTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                        HeaderTransitions="{TemplateBinding HeaderTransitions}"
                                        Footer="{TemplateBinding Footer}"
                                        FooterTemplate="{TemplateBinding FooterTemplate}"
                                        FooterTransitions="{TemplateBinding FooterTransitions}"
                                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only extend controls that inherit from UserControl the way you are trying (Like Page for example).

What you have to do is just create a class that inherits from ListView and modify default style for it.

```
<Style TargetType="my:CustomListView">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="..">
```

...

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Is there a way in the default style to specify the ItemTemplate and provide callbacks to events in the class file?

Comment: I think you can just set it via regular setter.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into it and see. Thanks for your help :)

It's a little frustrating that they changed functionality so you can't subclass other types of controls anymore :(

Comment: Ah, sorry. As it is just a Style, this is going to be a little harder. You will have to wire the up by overriding onApplyTemplate.